# access class variable in ruby

Tags: ruby, class, variables

Why class variable in ruby does not behave like static variable, how can I access it simply by doing Mytest.value, instead of MyTest.new.value?

```
class MyTest
  @@value=0

  def value
    @@value
  end
end

puts MyTest.new.value
```

Comment: It is best to not use class variables. I've completely removed them from my toolkit. Instead, use instance variables on your class, like Erik shows. If your instances also need access to them, give them methods that delegate to the class.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You want something like

```
class MyTest
  @@value = 0
  def self.value
    @@value
  end
end
```

The `self` makes it a class method, which the class calls directly.

Answer (score 2):

[EDIT] Read comments to know why not doing this.

```
class MyTest
  @value=0

  class << self
    attr_accessor :value
  end
end
```

Instead, if you really need to access variable in such ways, I suggest a simple module.

Otherwise, like Joshua Cheek commented on the original post, you should use Instance Variable for your class and have accessors.

Comment: While this behaves similarly, there are important differences between class variables and instance variables for class objects (the big one being how they are treated by inheritance).

Also, `class << self` is outdated notation. Recent Ruby versions have `singleton_class` and `define_singleton_method` methods, which are easier to read.

Comment: You are right, the right way of doing this is well, the answer you just posted.

Comment: The term "static" doesn't really apply in Ruby.